Encrypting hard drive in MacOS (Sonoma 14.4): Disk Utility does not have option to format hard drive as "Mac OS Extended (Journaled, Encrypted)"
My understanding is that APFS is for SSDs that perform well with random seek, but not for hard drives. Therefore, I want to format my hard drive with HFS+ ("Mac OS Extended").
And with encryption.
But Disk Utility doesn't have an option for it.

I've formatted the drive as GUID, but that didn't help.
I've tried performing an "Encrypt" using Finder on the drive, but that just changes it into APFS.
Did Apple remove support for HFS+ encryption?

Apparently this was a problem in 2020 too: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252122258?answerId=254028134022&sortBy=best#254028134022

Create Encrypted HFS+ Sparse Bundles with Spundle or hdiutil
The encrypted HFS options are no longer available from within diskutil itself on recent versions of macOS, but even as recently as macOS Sonoma you can still encrypt HFS+ disk images by passing the -encryption AES-256 flag to hdiutil create. This also works with other HFS+ variations including HFS+J and JHFS+X. You might also be able to do full-disk encryption using CoreStorage in a similar way to encrypt the whole logical volume, but I can't say for sure as I didn't specifically test that.
The freeware (free-as-in-beer, not FOSS) utility Spundle has an option specifically for creating encrypted HFS+J sparse bundles among other filesystem variants. The most recent version of the utility is v1.8 which works with Mojave and Sonoma, and there are other versions that work with earlier versions of the OS.
I found it instructive to see how Spundle was doing this. Since it isn't open source I couldn't examine the code directly, but if you watch your process list you can see it creating an encrypted sparse bundle by invoking the hdiutil disk image utility that comes with macOS to create an AES-256 encrypted 20TB HFS+J sparse bundle with a 400MB band size.
For example, assume you have an unencrypted 22TiB external HDD labeled Foo. Foo has been formatted as HFS+J to prevent some of the seek problems that reportedly still dog APFS on spinning platters. To create a 20TB encrypted HFS+J sparsebundle labaled Bar on the mounted volume, after setting your other options you can use Spundle v1.8 with HFS+ or HFS+J selected as the filesystem and change "Plain" (i.e. unencrypted) to AES-128 or AES-256 before clicking "Create".
Under the hood, this calls hdiutil similarly to the following minus the line-wrapping:
/usr/bin/hdiutil create \
    -size 20t \
    -type SPARSEBUNDLE \
    -encryption AES-256 \
    -stdinpass \
    -imagekey sparse-band-size=800000 \
    -fs HFS+J \
    -volname Bar \
    /Volumes/Foo/Bar.sparsebundle

Validating the Sparse Bundle is Encrypted
DiskUtil doesn't always report the encrypted status properly. However, you can verify that the sparse bundle, which acts as the backing store for your encrypted filesystem, is actually encrypted using hdiutil from the command line. For example:
hdiutil isencrypted /Volumes/Foo/Bar.sparsebundle | grep -E "^encrypted:"

This should return encrypted: YES among other details. If so, the sparse bundle is encrypted. Otherwise, you may have missed a step or failed to enter a valid password.
Notes, Caveats, and Cautions
Band Size
Selecting the right band size, especially for large images, is outside the scope of this answer. The system default for band size is 8.4 MB per band, which is entirely unsuitable for very large images as just enumerating the bands will cause severe performance issues. The Spundle author recommends sizing the bands to ensure the total number of bands remains <= 50,000 to prevent this problem. For large HDDs of 18-22TiB, 360MB per band for an 18TB image or 400MB for a 20TB image is going to be more performant for most use cases excluding incremental or differential backups.
Reserving Space for Filesystem Overhead on the Physical Drive
You might also want to reserve a few TiB by ensuring your maximum image size is smaller than your actual disk size as the sparse bundle format and HFS+ itself on the host drive each create some overhead. You also want to ensure you have some headroom for reallocation of bad blocks on the host drive.
For example, an empty 20TB sparse bundle on 22TiB of HDD uses ~6.6GiB of space—approximately 4.3GiB for the host HDD's HFS+J filesystem, plus roughly 2.3GiB for the encrypted HFS+J sparse bundle—even when freshly initialized. While not an exact science, I'd personally recommend leaving at least ~2TB (roughly 10%) free on the host filesystem out of caution, but you may decide you need more or less headroom, especially when the sparse bundle is defined as larger than the physical disk that it's on.
Your specific disk size, image counts, and storage use cases will certainly impact your choice of how much free space (if any) to reserve. In addition your sparse bundle band sizes, inodes used by both the host and internally within the image, and personal tastes regarding margins of safety may certainly affect the optimal settings for the amount of space to reserve.
Caution on Encryption Password Length
A "valid" password for encrypted filesystems also implies passwords of a length that can be handled by diskutil and other system utilities. This currently appears limited to no more than 31 or 63 characters, so check the length of your password or passphrase before creating the encrypted sparsebundle, and validate that you can mount and unmount the volume properly before committing any valuable data to the new disk image.

Maybe they removed it?

Unfortunately, Apple removed the ability to create HFS+ Encrypted volumes since Big Sur. –
adib
Jun 28, 2022 at 2:23

from https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/421267/523293
Although their documentation still mentions it, so maybe the documentation is outdated?
https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/disk-utility/dsku19ed921c/20.0/mac/11.0

Mac OS Extended (Journaled, Encrypted): Uses the Mac format, requires a password, and encrypts the partition.

Other discussions:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253810870?sortBy=best

